# Angular4, D3 V4 & Typescripts

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js

My environment setup is like this.

- Angular 4.1.2
- Angular-CLI 1.0.0
- @types/d3 4.8.0
- TypeScript

I am trying to integrate D3 V4 with my angular project. I am creating simple pie chart. But I am getting this error. Code has been copy and pasted [from](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887235). Only change is instead of CSV loader, I have used JSON loader.

```
private buildPieChart() {
    let svg = d3.select("svg"),
        width = +svg.attr("width"),
        height = +svg.attr("height"),
        radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
        g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

    let color = d3.scaleOrdinal(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

    let pie = d3.pie()
        .sort(null)
        .value(function(d) { return +d['population']; });

    let path = d3.arc()
        .outerRadius(radius - 10)
        .innerRadius(0);

    let label = d3.arc()
        .outerRadius(radius - 40)
        .innerRadius(radius - 40);

    d3.json("data.json", function(data) {
        console.log(data);

        let arc = g.selectAll(".arc")
            .data(pie(data))
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "arc");

        arc.append("path")
            .attr("d", path)
            .attr("fill", function (d) {
                return color(d.data.age);
            });

        arc.append("text")
            .attr("transform", function (d) {
                return "translate(" + label.centroid(d) + ")";
            })
            .attr("dy", "0.35em")
            .text(function (d) {
                return d.data.age;
            });
    });
}
```

[image]

I m getting error when I am assigning path to attribute 'd' of arc.

```
arc.append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .attr("fill", function (d) {
        return color(d.data.age);
    });
```

[image]

and also getting error at returning age from text function

```
arc.append("text")
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + label.centroid(d) + ")";
    })
    .attr("dy", "0.35em")
    .text(function (d) {
        return d.data.age;
    });
```

[image]

Comment: Try this `.text(function(d:any){ return d.data.age;})`

Comment: Second error for d.data.age got resolved by adding type any to d in function parameter

Comment: I was presuming for the first part you are not defining the type so type script may raise an error as shown by you in the screen shot. For path try this `.attr("d", <any> path` or may be something like this `.attr("d", function(d1){return path(d1)}`

Comment: I had a similar issue. The code sample ```.attr("d", <any>path)``` removed the error.

Answer (score 0):

In the `console` you probably see that it cant read data from `data.csv` or JSON file. Try to add data manualy, like: `const dataset = [.......];`
And than something like `let svg = d3.select("svg").data(dataset).enter()` at the start, than you dont need to do `d3.json.....`
But if you want to read data from file and put it to d3, than you need to do something like 
`this.data = Object.keys(data).map(key => dataset[key]);
const dataset = [this.data[0].age, this.data[0].populatin] ....`(and you can put it in array with `index` to get all ages and population).